# I can not boot windows XP Pro after installing Trusty Tahr 14.04

Tags: dual-boot

When I installed ubuntu I chose the option of Run alonside Windows Xp Professional. When the installation completed the computer restart itself and it brought me to the purple ubuntu boot menu. If I were to select the option to boot Windows Xp Professional then the screen would go blank(black screen) and nothing will happen it will bring to the same menu. On a side note I use XP to use software that is not supported by wine yet and want to use ubuntu for web surfing. What can I do to go back to using XP?

Here is the link provided from the boot repair report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10757765/

The report also has this message in the end- Please repair the bootsector of the sda 1 partition. This can be performed via tools such as TestDisk.

Comment: Please grab Boot Repair report and attach it to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "sudo update-grub", that will find every OS it can on your hard drive and add them to GRUB. If that does not work, then there might be a problem with XP's bootloader.